# org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The system is attempting to engage a module that is not available: addressing

Tags: java, eclipse, soap, apache-axis

Hi I need to execute a jar file, but when I am executing, I get this error. Some help? I was googling lot of hours, but I can't find a solution.

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The system is attempting to engage a module that is not available: addressing
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisConfiguration.engageModule(AxisConfiguration.java:584)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisConfiguration.engageGlobalModules(AxisConfiguration.java:705)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.engageModules(DeploymentEngine.java:831)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.FileSystemConfigurator.engageGlobalModules(FileSystemConfigurator.java:142)
at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:94)
at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:210)
at es.spee.meyss.proveedorcentro.application.ws.impl.ProveedorCentroTFWSStub.getContextConfiguration(ProveedorCentroTFWSStub.java:189)
at es.spee.meyss.proveedorcentro.application.ws.impl.ProveedorCentroTFWSStub.<init>(ProveedorCentroTFWSStub.java:185)
at es.spee.meyss.proveedorcentro.application.ws.impl.ProveedorCentroTFWSStub.<init>(ProveedorCentroTFWSStub.java:198)
at es.spee.meyss.proveedorcentro.cliente.business.services.impl.ProveedorCentroSvcImpl.getProveedorCentroWS(ProveedorCentroSvcImpl.java:149)
at es.spee.meyss.proveedorcentro.cliente.business.services.impl.ProveedorCentroSvcImpl.validarObtenerDatosCentro(ProveedorCentroSvcImpl.java:193)
at es.spee.meyss.proveedorcentro.cliente.business.services.impl.ProveedorCentroSvcImpl.validarObtenerDatosCentro(ProveedorCentroSvcImpl.java:170)
at es.spee.meyss.proveedorcentro.validador.ProveedorCentroTFValidador.validarObtenerDatosCentro(ProveedorCentroTFValidador.java:159)
at es.spee.meyss.proveedorcentro.validador.ProveedorCentroTFValidador.main(ProveedorCentroTFValidador.java:49)
```

Comment: Do you have the addressing.mar in your modules directory ?

Comment: Now i get another error.. but thanks anyways

Comment: If you manged to find a solution, please provide it. It'll help other people who might have the same issue.

Comment: I don't know about how he disappeared, I did  a lot of things, sorry. If I find it, I'll post here.

Comment: I have the same issue! Would you please share how you did it!

Comment: I have addressing.mar in my modules dir, and still get the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Find the WEB-INF/conf/axis2.xml and comment out following line:

```
<module ref="addressing"/>
```

it worked for me