# Axis2 Fault : The system is attempting to engage a module that is not available: addressing

Tags: apache-axis, ws-addressing

I have the addressing module in my modules folder as well. I have the `<module ref="addressing"/>` uncommented as well. But, it is still giving the error. I searched in another thread on Stack Overflow:

[org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The system is attempting to engage a module that is not available: addressing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31721859/org-apache-axis2-axisfault-the-system-is-attempting-to-engage-a-module-that-is)

But, it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer- The axis2 war was working on JBoss Server but not on WAS server.

Solution- In axis2.xml file, there is a parameter 'EnableChildFirstClassLoading' which was commented, uncommenting it and deploying axis2 war again solved the issue.

Needed to make the above mentioned change on WAS server only.